# Ошибка при выполнении PHP artisan Serve

Tags: php, laravel

Я новичок в Laravel,выдает ошибку при выполнении команды PHP artisan serve

Warning: require(C:\OpenServer\domains\newtask/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\OpenServer\domains\newtask\artisan on line 18

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\OpenServer\domains\newtask/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.') in C:\OpenServer\domains\newtask\artisan on line 18

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Видимо вы не до конца прочитали инструкции по установке Laravel, где говорится про Composer.